# Is there a good and robust way to fake the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am developing an app that behaves Differently depending the current day in the month.

For instance, if it is the 1st - 5th of the month (no matter the month) you can do action X. But from the 5th - 15th you can only do action Y.

(This is of course some vague way to demonstrate the need)

---

I have managed to "fake" the datetime in the backend using DynamoDB by the user request (only for development of course).

Many parts in the app uses the MySQL db, which auto adds the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to a column, "time_created". In these parts, there are some calculations on the dates differences - between "time_created" and the "current_backend_time". So, if I fake the time to be lets say the 15th of the month, but it is really the 1st of the month, my test-user fails since there are too big differences between these timestamps.

---

(Hope I explained the need correctly)

**I am looking for a way to also fake the time for the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.**

I don't want to set the time by myself since there are also "time_updated" and more columns which I want MySQL to update by itself.

---

**Is there a way to achieve that?**

**Is there a way to do it for each user? meaning to have this "fake time" for each user in the database?**

- Database is hosted in AWS RDS.
- Code written in Python.

Comment: MySQL's current timestamp comes from the system time, which you wouldn't be able to change on AWS RDS.

Comment: Oh really ? :( 
Are you familiar with another way of achieving what I want?

Comment: A clarification... the current timestamp is set for the session using the system time, but you can change it with "set timestamp=[a unix time]". In your case, you could do something like "set timestamp=unix_timestamp(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-03 %T'))" to change current_timestamp() to the 3rd of the current month and year. It will apply to inserts in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You might have heard about test driven development (TDD) https://testdriven.io/blog/modern-tdd/

Some people don't like it, I'm currently trying to learn it the right way and use it in my projects.

Part of it is to seperate details from the main logic to be able to test them. (seperating the details has nothing to do with TDD, as this practice can be used without TDD)

The basic idea is to create a mockup class for your SQL impelmentation, this way you can simulate a database connection with all the values you need.

After you are done developing the logic, the DBMockup class will be replaced with your real SQL connection, with the same methods the mockup class uses.

This can speed up your development process and at the end you know exactly what your SQL database has to look like.

```
from datetime import datetime


class DBMockup:
    def __init__(self):
        self._records = [
            [1, 'test record', datetime.now().isoformat()],
            [2, 'test record 2', '2023-01-10T13:35:55.436682'],
        ]

    def get_record(self, idx):
        return [record for record in self._records if record[0] == idx][0]

    def create_record(self, record: list):
        max_idx = max([record[0] for record in self._records])
        record.insert(0, int(max_idx) + 1)
        self._records.append(record)

    def get_last_record(self):
        return self._records[-1]


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DBMockup()

    def get_record(self, idx):
        return self.db.get_record(idx)

    def create_record(self, record):
        self.db.create_record(record)

    def get_last_record(self):
        return self.db.get_last_record()


db = Database()
print(db.get_record(1))
db.create_record(['test 3', datetime.now().isoformat()])
print(db.get_last_record())
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! This is (in some way) what I do in unittesting, but I was looking for a way to solve a "real user" that uses the app, clicks buttons etc. Not as a script, I want to call the real endpoints and all. 
I will point here as well that the DB is a development DB, which is different from production DB, so no worries about that.